# Broadcast Live Streaming on a website with an added graphical overlay

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming

I was doing some research on Live Streaming. I want to develop a solution where I will collect live streams from multiple remote cameras on my website, modify the stream with a custom text banner (i.e. we have on news TV channel, football match) at the bottom and broadcast it to all.

I know there are Flash plugins available for video streaming and editing, but I want to build this web app to be mobile friendly and responsive.

HTML5 could be used to display multiple video streams on the website, but how can I add a text banner, graphs or any other frame on a running live stream?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, and the way that gives you the most quality and control over presentation, is to just do it on the client application.  It sounds like you control this, so just modify your application to fetch a data stream alongside the video stream.  This will work great assuming that you control the client side, and exact synchronization isn't critical.

Assuming you don't control the players at all and you need to bake this all into the video, there are a variety of tools you can use.  GStreamer, FFmpeg, even VLC depending on your requirements.  If you need something more interactive, OBS might be something to look into as well.

Comment: I was looking for a web base solution for live stream editing.